# Folder Icon Change

Tags: c#

I am changing the folder icons with c# function. Its working fine but the problem is its working for first time. I mean I am not able to change the icon for the folder for which I have changed the icon already.
Here is the code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LPSHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS FolderSettings = new LPSHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS();
    FolderSettings.dwMask = 0x10;
    FolderSettings.pszIconFile = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\TortoiseOverlays\icons\XPStyle\ModifiedIcon.ico";
    FolderSettings.iIconIndex = 0;

    UInt32 FCS_READ = 0x00000001;
    UInt32 FCS_FORCEWRITE = 0x00000002;
    UInt32 FCS_WRITE = FCS_READ | FCS_FORCEWRITE;

    string pszPath = @"D:\Downloaded Data";
    UInt32 HRESULT = SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(ref FolderSettings, pszPath, FCS_WRITE);
    //Console.WriteLine(HRESULT.ToString("x"));
    //Console.ReadLine();

}

[DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern UInt32 SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(ref LPSHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS pfcs, string pszPath, UInt32 dwReadWrite);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct LPSHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS
{
    public UInt32 dwSize;
    public UInt32 dwMask;
    public IntPtr pvid;
    public string pszWebViewTemplate;
    public UInt32 cchWebViewTemplate;
    public string pszWebViewTemplateVersion;
    public string pszInfoTip;
    public UInt32 cchInfoTip;
    public IntPtr pclsid;
    public UInt32 dwFlags;
    public string pszIconFile;
    public UInt32 cchIconFile;
    public int iIconIndex;
    public string pszLogo;
    public UInt32 cchLogo;
}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please show the code changing the icon the first and consecutive times.

Comment: I did the changes in question.

Comment: Check if the hidden desktop.ini file is getting updated.  Other than that, Explorer caching icons is never not a problem.

Comment: Exactly the problem. Its changing the desktop.ini file. This is what I am getting on when I open desktop.ini                  [.ShellClassInfo] IconResource=C:\Users\deepak.chopra\Pictures\CD-Folder.ico,0
". The "CD-Folder.ico" is the icon I applied on "D:\Downloaded Data" folder.

Comment: I have found a solution to the above problem. I am posting here to reference for others. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9331/Create-Icons-for-Folders-in-Windows-Explorer-Using

Comment: Code is not changing folder icon. I have run the code after changing icon image and iIconIndex set to 0. It is not changing the folder icon. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 4):

I've faced with similar issue.
Just remove the desktop.ini file before calling the function for the second time.
The same scenario is used if you would like to clear folder icon:

1. Remove desktop.ini.
2. Omit the following lines:

....

```
FolderSettings.pszIconFile = @"{icon path}";
FolderSettings.iIconIndex = 0;
```

....

Answer (score 3):

Just change

```
UInt32 FCS_WRITE = FCS_READ | FCS_FORCEWRITE;
```

to

```
UInt32 FCS_WRITE = FCS_FORCEWRITE;
```

When you run next time the FCS_WRITE = FCS_READ, so it wont write agian.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just for completion, the code in question looks OK, but the 3rd param in the 
SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings call must be FCS_FORCEWRITE in order to change the settings if already present. (FCS_WRITE will set it ONLY if values NOT already present)

See docs about that parameter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762199(v=vs.85).aspx