# C#:How to program a service that changes the icon of a folder based on the content?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, filesystemwatcher

I want to make a program that runs as a service and changes the folder icon based on its foldercontent, like svn does. And I also want to change the icon and the behavior of a folder if the name is example.someextension .

How may I programmatically achieve this and which namespaces or libraries could do that?

Comment: What have you tired? What is the main problem?

Comment: I don´t know how to change the registry because Microsoft.Win32.Registry doesn´t work, i don´t know how to read folders and subfolders and the files in it and i don´t know how to change icons of a folder.

Comment: And I don´t know how to write a program that runs as a service instead of a process

Comment: You can use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx), [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx), [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx), [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) classes. Tutorial [How to create win service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464(v=vs.71).aspx) and [how to change folder icon question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277492/folder-icon-change). Good luck

Comment: Ok thats an good answer, I hope on these pages is some example code, too. (When you write this as answer I´d be glad :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

- [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx),
  [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx)
  to get directory name, subdirectories, files in directory.
- [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx),
  [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)
  to get file name, content, extensions.
- [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464(v=vs.71).aspx)
  to learn how to create windows service.
- And [this
  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277492/folder-icon-change)
  to change folder icon.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a filesystem folder, you can set the folder's icon using an ini file.

Make your service write a (hidden & system) file *called Desktop.ini* to the desired folder, along with a hidden copy of the icon you want that folder to display:

your file should contain something like this:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconFile=myFolderIcon.ico
IconIndex=0
ConfirmFileOp=0
OriginalIcon=%
```

Programs like Art-Icons use this mechanism to allow folder customization. The only drawback I have noticed with this is that folders do not necessarily update to use the new icon immediately. Sometimes you have to reset the icon cache to force it to display!

Example: (your folder will already contain hidden copies of icons "folderA.ico" and "folderB.ico"):

```
string[] lines = new string[] { "[.ShellClassInfo]", "IconFile=folderA.ico", "IconIndex=0", "ConfirmFileOp=0", "OriginalIcon=%" };

if(!stimulus)
{
   lines[1] = "IconFile=folderB.ico";
}

File.WriteAllLines("Disk:\\MyFolder\\Desktop.ini", lines);
```