# Change folder icon to dll icon without desktop.ini

Tags: c#, icons, directory

I want to change the icon of a specific folder and I'm using an **icon from windows dlls** (ImageRes.dll to be more specific). But **I do NOT want to create a "Desktop.ini"** file in the folder, instead I'm using SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings function from shell32 described in this post: [Folder Icon Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277492/folder-icon-change)
My problem is that I can't figure out a way to use that function with an icon from a dll. I tried passing @"C:\Windows\system32\ImageRes.dll,37" or @"%SystemRoot%\system32\ImageRes.dll,37" as FolderSettings.pszIconFile but that didn't work.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the file name in `pszIconFile` and 37 in `iIconIndex`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering why I didn't realize it myself! Now I have a new problem: the problem described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277492/folder-icon-change I can't change the icon twice! Once I change it, I can't change it to another icon! What should I do?

Comment: I found the solution. As the answer to the above question suggests, We should fist delete "Desktop.ini" if exists and then use that function ...